# Mysql query with number of joins and cases - adding more joins and sub-queries

Tags: mysql, sql

So far I've got this:

```
SELECT connections.id,
       connections.word_id,
       connections.order_id,
       connections.top,
       connections.deleted,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(connections.modified)) AS modified_ago,
       words_en.word,
       (CASE WHEN words_en.user_id = 1 THEN "You" ELSE words_en.user_id END) AS created_by
FROM connections, words_en
WHERE connections.word_id = words_en.id AND connections.user_id = 1
ORDER BY connections.order_id
```

I want to add few things, but I can't get syntax correct.

1. `(CASE WHEN words_en.user_id = 1 THEN "You" ELSE words_en.user_id END)` here, when ELSE, instead of ID i'd like to get `name_surname` column of this user from users table. So I need to do another join? But since it is within case, how would I do that?
2. `connections.word_id` from the SELECT. besides ID, I also want to know how many times this word_id is present in connections table. But excluding current user from the list.

I hope explanation was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rewrite your query using ANSI joins, and add table aliases, like this:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.word_id,
       c.order_id,
       c.top,
       c.deleted,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.modified)) AS modified_ago,
       words_en.word,
       (CASE WHEN words_en.user_id = 1 THEN "You" ELSE w.user_id END) AS created_by
FROM connections c
JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
WHERE c.user_id = 1
ORDER BY c.order_id
```

Now extending this query becomes easier: to bring in the user by `w.user_id`, add another join:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.word_id,
       c.order_id,
       c.top,
       c.deleted,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.modified)) AS modified_ago,
       words_en.word,
       (CASE WHEN words_en.user_id = 1 THEN "You" ELSE u. name_surname END) AS created_by
FROM connections c
JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
JOIN users u ON w.user_id = u.id
WHERE c.user_id = 1
ORDER BY c.order_id
```

To add the count, use a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.word_id,
       c.order_id,
       c.top,
       c.deleted,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.modified)) AS modified_ago,
       words_en.word,
       (CASE WHEN words_en.user_id = 1 THEN "You" ELSE u. name_surname END) AS created_by,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM connections cc
           WHERE cc.word_id=c.word_id     -- It's the same word
             AND cc.user_id <> c.user_id  -- user by a different user
       ) as uses_by_others
FROM connections c
JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
JOIN users u ON w.user_id = u.id
WHERE c.user_id = 1
ORDER BY c.order_id
```

Comment: I'm on the last step, and You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM connections cc
           WHERE cc.word_id = c.' at line 9

Comment: got it I was missing , comma :P

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT connections.id,
       connections.word_id,
       connections.order_id,
       connections.top,
       connections.deleted,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(connections.modified)) AS modified_ago,
       words_en.word,
       (CASE WHEN words_en.user_id = 1 THEN "You" ELSE users.name_surname END) AS created_by
FROM connections JOIN words
WHERE connections.word_id = words_en.id AND connections.user_id = 1 JOIN users ON users.id=words_en.user_id
ORDER BY connections.order_id
```

I cant tell from your answer how to link the users table,post the tables schemas.Just a wild guess.